# How can I select features with both multiple attributes and NULL values

Tags: arcmap, attribute-table, definition-query

I'm using ArcMap and am trying to filter a selection from my attribute table that contains both NULL and regular values but it is not working.

The query should only select John values with NULL, Addition, and Construction. Below I did my best but the NULL are not helping.  What is the solution?

```
Select * FROM Table_name WHERE:
Usr_name ='John' AND Project_name IS NULL OR Project_name IN ('Addition', 'Construction')
```

Input

```
Object_ID   Object_type Usr_name    Project_name
 1            Triangle    John         Addition
 2             Square     Peter        Addition
 3            Polygon     Mary         Addition
 4             Circle     John       Substracion
 5            Polygon     Mary          <Null>
 6             Square     Mary          <Null>
 7             Square     John          <Null>
 8            Polygon     John         Obstacle
 9              Hex       John       Construction
```

The minimal desired output result

```
Object_ID   Object_type Usr_name    Project_name
  1           Triangle    John        Addition
  7            Square     John         <Null>
  9             Hex       John      Construction
```

Comment: The order of precedence for the `OR` operator is rarely what you think it is. Whenever you have an `OR`, make sure you have explicit parenthesis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a selection statement doesn't behave as you expect, it may be because of the order in which the sub-expressions are evaluated. You can override that order by adding extra parenthesis. In your case it should probably look like:

```
Select* FROM Table_name WHERE:
Usr_name ='John' AND (Project_name IS NULL OR Project_name IN ('Addition', 'Construction'))
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked.